# Issue with infoWindows with multiple markers and directionsDisplay variables in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm trying to display how distance and how minutes are between two markers in Google Maps API v3 and use these information to override the default infoWindow text that appears when the `directionsService` is fired, I think there is a asyncronous problem with `calcRoute()` and the `infoWindows`. This is an example code that reproduces the error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'map': map }); 
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;
        function initMap(locations){
            function calcRoute(latdest, lngdest) {
                var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.571064, -46.645424);
                var end = new google.maps.LatLng(latdest, lngdest)
                var request = {origin:start,destination:end,travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING};
                directionsService.route(request, function(result, status){
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), {zoom: 10,center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.571064, -46.645424),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;
            var image = null;
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    calcRoute(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
                    infowindow.setContent(directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text+" - "+directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='initMap([["Vila Noemia", -23.670237, -46.467286],["Osasco", -23.535465, -46.794234],["Guarulhos", -23.458911, -46.526912]]);'>
    <div id="mapcanvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Please note that if you click one marker, and then another, the second marker will show the desired result but that information belongs to the first marker... How can I force the order of execution to avoid the async?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I have tried to use `callbacks`, `$.deferreds` and `$.when` And none of this has worked for me, although I'm not 100% sure that I implemented well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to open the infowindow in the DirectionsService callback function where the data is available.

(you may also want to suppress the existing markers from the directions service)

InfoWindow click listener:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            calcRoute(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

Updated `calcRoute` function:

```
function calcRoute(latdest, lngdest) {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.571064, -46.645424);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(latdest, lngdest)
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            infowindow.setContent(directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text + " - " + directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
        }
    });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ya86ckbq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  map: map,
  suppressMarkers: true
});
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initMap(locations) {
  function calcRoute(latdest, lngdest) {
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.571064, -46.645424);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(latdest, lngdest)
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        infowindow.setContent(directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text + " - " + directionsDisplay.directions.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text);
      }
    });
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcanvas'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.571064, -46.645424),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var marker, i;
  var image = null;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        calcRoute(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  initMap([
    ["Vila Noemia", -23.670237, -46.467286],
    ["Osasco", -23.535465, -46.794234],
    ["Guarulhos", -23.458911, -46.526912]
  ]);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapcanvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, There is a possibility not remove the point A (the start point)? That was a little example, but in my real code the `start` is the first element of the array locations: `var start = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]);` So I don't want to remove it.

Comment: I don't want to remove, but `hide` the markers (start and end), and when user click another marker unhide hidded markers, is this possible?

Comment: You don't have to use `suppressMarkers`, but if you use it, it removes all the markers (but you have your own markers, no reason you can't change them).  The sensor parameter is no longer required in the script include, your key is suggested (but not required) if it is on your own website, to allow you to track usage.

Comment: Your comments are probably best captured in a new question.

Comment: You're right, I will organize and make a new question, thanks for the tips!