# How to Modify the InfoWindow Of Goole Map DirectionRender markers

Tags: google-maps

DirectionRender plot the Markers Like A,B,C.....as waypoint between Route. If we click on that Marker it shows the Default InfoWindow which contain the Address. So I want to put my custom InfoWindow on that Markeres How to do this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the infoWindow when using google directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597630/changing-the-infowindow-when-using-google-directions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps V3 - waypoints + infowindow with random text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083639/google-maps-v3-waypoints-infowindow-with-random-text)

Comment: related question: [Issue with infoWindows with multiple markers and directionsDisplay variables in Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060413/issue-with-infowindows-with-multiple-markers-and-directionsdisplay-variables-in)

Answer (score 0):

You can give custom content to your infowindow by creating a variable like:

```
var content = '<h1>Custom heading</h1>' + '<p>Custom paragraph</p>';
```

and pass this variable in google.maps.Infowindow as:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: content,
   maxWidth: 350
});
```

and add an event listener as:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
 );
```